# Is there a way I can get the count of all entries of data created by their day of week for each week

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, asp.net-core

For example, I add data from sunday to saturday for this week. Next week, I add another set of data from sunday saturday to friday. I want the count to be done weekly.
What I have done so far with linq gets all the data but just by the days of week not for each week. Thanks

```
            var getallemployees = _context.Users.ToList();

            var employeecoupon = (from coup in getemployeecoupon
                                 join emplo in getallemployees on coup.PhoneNumber equals emplo.PhoneNumber
                                 where coup.CreationTime.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Sunday 
                                 && coup.CreationTime.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Saturday
                                 select new CouponDTO
                                 {
                                     PhoneNumber = coup.PhoneNumber,
                                     Email = emplo.Email,
                                     DateCreated = coup.CreationTime,
                                     DateUsed = coup.DateUsed,
                                 }).Count();
```

Comment: What are your results may look like?

Comment: It's a count. I filter the data by the creationTime as shown in the linq query employeecoupon. So when I call the action this week from sunday to saturday, I get the count of data stored this week. When I call the action next week I get the count of data stored next week

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(...) function described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_Calendar_GetWeekOfYear_System_DateTime_System_Globalization_CalendarWeekRule_System_DayOfWeek_):
Remember to add **using System.Globalization;** I've modified my example a bit - but it should communicate the idea. Ideally you could extract the WeekOfYear as soon as the coupon is issued.

This solution also assumes that you have access to, and are allowed to change your CouponDTO.

From there you can either send the weeknumber that you desire should you wish to filter your entries; or group them by WeekOfYear if you want to see all entries.

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        var getallemployees = _context.Users.ToList();
        var getemployeecoupon = _context.EmployeeCoupons.ToList(); // for demo purposes; change accordingly

        CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Calendar myCal = myCI.Calendar;
        CalendarWeekRule myCWR = myCI.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
        DayOfWeek myFirstDOW = myCI.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

        // You can call the maCal.GetWeekOfYear function whenever your original coupon is created; then you won't need this iteration
        foreach (EmployeeCoupon coup in getemployeecoupon)
            coup.WeekOfYear = myCal.GetWeekOfYear(coup.CreationTime, myCWR, myFirstDOW);

        var employeecoupon = (from coup in getemployeecoupon
                              join emplo in getallemployees on coup.PhoneNumber equals emplo.PhoneNumber
                              where coup.CreationTime.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Sunday
                              && coup.CreationTime.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Saturday
                              select new CouponDTO
                              {
                                  PhoneNumber = coup.PhoneNumber,
                                  Email = emplo.Email,
                                  DateCreated = coup.CreationTime,
                                  DateUsed = coup.DateUsed,
                                  WeekOfYear = coup.WeekOfYear,
                              }).Count();

    }

    public class CouponDTO
    {
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int WeekOfYear { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUsed { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeCoupon
    {
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public int WeekOfYear { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUsed { get; set; }
    }
```